# SharePoint 2013 Quicklinks in page

Tags: 2013, url, quick-links

When I embed a LINK in my pages from my LINKS library, instead of taking the visitor to the actual URL/page of the link, it takes you to an extra step per below;
http://xxxx.xx.xxx/whs/Lists/Link%20Library/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
..and then you can click on the link and go to the URL/page.

Is there a way to bypass the extra step and go directly to the actual URL/Page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the information in your question I understand that "Link Library" is a list and you have 2 columns title and hyper link column. You have added a list view web part on a page with title column.

You need a way to open your hyperlinks instead of clicking on title link and navigating from hyperlink on DispForm.aspx page.

If my assumption is correct, then you can make below small changes.

- Edit your List View Web Part.
- Edit current view.
- Choose "Hyper Link" column instead of title column.
- Save your changes.

Suggestion (if you want to add quick links to a site page):
There is a "Summary Links" web part in SharePoint to show quick links on a site page which works with advanced settings (Images to each link, ordering, grouping).

- Edit your page
- Add a web part
- Select "Conent Rollup" category and select "Summary Links" web part.
- Configure links by clicking "Add a link" link.

Let me know if you are looking for different from above one.

Comment: OK, both makes sense, I will take a look and see what works best for me.. Thanks Mate..

Comment: Hi Venkat, 
No matter how I format my list, the link still takes me to the 'extra' step instead of directly to URL.
e.g. http://xxx.xxx.xxx/whs/Lists/Link%20Library/DispForm.aspx?ID=1

Comment: I am not sure how your list view settings and list columns. Is it possible to update those in your questions?